# Writing to compound SQL table with C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a newbie to the C#, SQL, and  ASP.NET MVC world. I have to write to the following SQL tables (can't use SQL have to use C# with MVC):

***Read-Write***

```
Group
-----------------
id -- identity
name -- varchar

GroupCompanies
----------------
groupId -- fk link to Group.id
companyId -- fk link to Company.id

GroupSoftware
---------------
groupId -- fk link to Group.id
softwareId -- fk link to Software.id
companyId -- fk link to Company.id
```

There are separate read-only tables where data is sourced from to make the above compound tables ("GroupCompanies" and "GroupSoftware"):

***Read-only***

```
Companies
-----------------
id -- identity
name -- varchar

Software
-----------------
id -- identity
name -- varchar
```

On the page, called 'Create', I'm working on, I have **three fields in the View**:

**- Name** //Needs to write to Group.ID. Will then have to be paired with software and companies.

**- Companies** //Needs to write to GroupCompanies by pairing selected Company.ID with the ID of the above created name.

**- Software** //Needs to write to GroupSoftware by pairing selected Company.ID,  the above created name, AND with Software.ID.

I need to write in the name of a new Group, send it to the "Groups" Table. This is no biggie. I can successfully make this one work.

The other two fields  ("companies" and "software" ) are drop-down lists. I need to pair the "Company" values (which are the IDs in string format, so they will need to be converted to integers on post) with the "Software" values (also IDs as string) and the newly created group on Post.

**Now here's the thing:  How to catch the value strings as integers mapped to the correct object upon Posting the fields, and then write them to three tables at once? Since the "GroupSoftware" table depends on "GroupCompanies" and "Groups", and "GroupCompanies" depends on "Groups", I need to execute the commands in this order. Furthermore I don't know how to write on a table that requires IDs from the other tables with C# and ASP.NET MVC.**

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated!

PS: Remember, I'm new, I'm an idiot, so please be nice! :D

Some code for reference:
MVC VIEW

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create a Group";
}
<h2>createGroup</h2>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Group</legend>
@Html.Action("Create")
@Html.Action("softwareList")
@Html.Action("companyList")
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

MVC CONTROLLER THAT NEEDS TO BE MODIFIED

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult softwareList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> listSelectListItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (Software software in db.Software)
        {
            SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = software.SoftwareName,
                Value = software.SoftwareID.ToString(), //The items in the list have a   string value of SoftwareID.
            };
            listSelectListItem.Add(selectListItem);
        }

        softwareViewModel softwareviewmodel = new softwareViewModel(); //instantiates dummy container
        softwareviewmodel.Applications = listSelectListItem; //the list represent the 'software' in the dummy. A value is a piece of Array.
        return PartialView(softwareviewmodel);//shows the dummy container.
    }
```

^This is for software drop down list, the "groupcompanies" one is the same except with 'company' replacing 'software'.

MVC Model Class

```
public class softwareViewModel
{
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Software { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<string> Selectedsoftware { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: nobody will read you entire details. Be specific and precise. What is the issue? What have you tried that is not working?

Comment: "I have to write to the following SQL tables (can't use SQL)" WTF?

Comment: Hello Ehsan, I'm trying to keep it as precise as possible. Modified a few things to make it more legible.

banging, I have a set of SQL tables I need to write to with C#. I'm not allowed to use SQL on the tables directly.

Comment: What Object-Relational Mapping solution are you using in your code?  Chances are it has a way to save changes to the Database that is probably what you want here.  Alternatively, you could do stored procedures if you really had to get down to the basics of things here.

Comment: Is it existing solution implemented before your changes or are you trying to create new? If that is existing then try to find how data access layer is implemented. There might be entity framework, classic ADO.NET or other approaches.

Comment: Hello JB King, I am too much of a n00b to actually understand your question. Are you asking on how I am writing these things to database? I'm thinking of using the following commands to do the writing of the final integers:
            db.whatevertable.Add(caughtintegers);
            db.SaveChanges();

The solution already exists, I used Visual Studio 2012 to generate the Model for me from the database with entity framework (Add New Item> Visual C# > ADO.NET Entity Data Model.)

I'm trying to append rows to the existing tables with C# and ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Consider a [PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=entity+framework) subscription.

Comment: I'm sorry Ihor, I answered your question in my last comment, too (forgot to post your name). Josh, I have a Pluralsight account (that's how I've been learning most of this) but can't find the info I'm looking for.